# I don't have prime profile at nvidia xserver settings

Tags: nvidia, bumblebee, framerate

I was using windows before and I was playing cs go without any ping with high fps. I am using ubuntu 14.04 now. I have very low fps although I decreased the video settings. I am using ASUS N550k, Geforce GTX 850 M display card. Moreover I installed bumblebee. 
Thanks for help.

Comment: Please be more specific. [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/754994/edit) your post and explain which game (Counter-Strike: Global Offensive?) you mean, how (wine / native steam on linux?) do you play the game and which gfx driver yre installed.

Answer (score 0):

Use `nvidia-prime` instead of `bumblebee` and to make sure that everything works as expected, remove all NVIDIA software and the bumblebee packages as well. Because you have quite new graphics hardware, it might be a good idea to install the latest official stable NVIDIA drivers.

Open a terminal and execute these commands :

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia* '^bumblebee.*'  
sudo reboot
```

Select the Ubuntu menu entry from the GRUB menu and  press the <kbd>E</kbd> key.
Add `nouveau.modeset=0` at the end of the `linux` line and press <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot.
Note : Put a `Space` between the last character of the line and `nouveau.modeset=0`.

Open a terminal and execute these commands :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-361 nvidia-prime
sudo reboot
```

You can choose which graphics you want to use from NVIDIA X Server Settings (PRIME Profiles).

Comment: Does the `nouveau.modeset=0` need to be added before I install the driver and prime? And also, is this change suppose to stick? I mean I've applied this  change but next time I reboot and I go to GRUB and press `E`, my change is not there any more. Is this change automatically removed?

Comment: @Mehran It has to be added **before** installing the drivers and once they are installed and you rebooted the system, there's nothing else you need to do ... everything should work as expected, right out-of-the-box. :)

Comment: Thanks. And how about the fact that the change to grub menu is gone after I reboot. Is that expected? I mean after I reboot when I go to grub menu and press `e`, the `nouveau.modeset=0`is not there anymore. Is this a problem?

Comment: @Mehran Editing the GRUB menu is a "one-time-action" ... if you want to make it a permanent solution, you have to add a parameter to `/etc/default/grub` and run `sudo update-grub` afterwards. :)

Comment: Thanks. I guess I have to uninstall the driver and install it once more. I hope it still works.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to try your commands but I get a lot of "SCHED ERROR" and after all I could not open my computer. What Should I do now?